# Shell command to parse/print stream

Tags: unix, grep, posix

### Specific question

What is a shell command to turn strings like this

```
class A(B, C):
```

into sets of strings like this

```
B -> A; 
C -> A;
```

Where A, B, and C are all of the form \w+ and, where I've written "B, C" I really mean any number of terms separated by commas and whitespace. I.e. "B, C" could equally be "B" or "B, C, D, E".

### Big picture

I'm visualizing the class hierarchy of a Python project. I'm looking into a directory for all .py files, grepping for class declarations and then converting them to [DOT format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_language). So far I've used find and grep to get a list of lines. I've done what is above in [a small python script](https://gist.github.com/3332164). If possible I'd like to use just the standard unix toolchain instead. Ideally I'd like to find another composable tool to pipe into and out of and complete the chain.

Comment: Python is pretty standard on UNIX systems these days. Unless you're expecting to run on a router or TV or something, you're probably good with what you have.

Comment: I'd still like to see if there is a standard solution for this. This is because (1) it'd be nice not to have to switch into Python (2) I find that knowing these tools does make me more productive, even though I have a powerful scripting language at my disposal.

Comment: Python *is* a "standard" solution as much as anything else is. It's an interpreter just like all the others. Your alternatives are a whole not more primative. Sed or Awk are pretty ancient and could both probably get you there. Perl is another option and is only a little newer than awk, and would certainly be faster. You could probably write it in Bash, but not so easily in sh. Just remember that Perl is older than Bash, so arguably more "standard" ... whatever that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want primitive? This sed script should work on every UNIX since V7 (but I haven't tested it on anything really old so be careful). Run it as `sed -n -f scriptfile infile > outfile`

```
: loop
/^class [A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\([A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*, *\)*[A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*):$/{
h
s/^class \([A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\)(\([A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\)[,)].*/\2 -> \1;/
p
g
s/\(class [A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\)[A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*,* */\1/
b loop
}
```

Those are BREs (Basic Regular Expressions). They don't have a `+` operator (that's only found in Extended Regular Expressions) and they definitely don't have `\w` (which was invented by perl). So your simple `\w+` becomes `[A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` and I had to use it several times, resulting in major ugliness.

In pseudocode form, what the thing does is:

```
while the line matches /^class \w+(comma-separated-list-of \w+):$/ {
    save the line in the hold space
    capture the outer \w and the first \w in the parentheses
    replace the entire line with the new string "\2 -> \1;" using the captures
    print the line
    retrieve the line from the hold space
    delete the first member of the comma-separated list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module to parse Python is easy as, well, Python.

```python
import ast
class ClassDumper(ast.NodeVisitor):
  def visit_ClassDef(self, clazz):
    def expand_name(expr):
      if isinstance(expr, ast.Name):
        return expr.id
      if isinstance(expr, ast.Attribute):
        return '%s.%s' % (expand_name(expr.value), expr.attr)
      return ast.dump(expr)
    for base in clazz.bases:
      print '%s -> %s;' % (clazz.name, expand_name(base))
    ClassDumper.generic_visit(self, clazz)
ClassDumper().visit(ast.parse(open(__file__).read()))
```

(This isn't quite right w.r.t. nesting, as it'll output `Inner -> Base;` instead of `Outer.Inner -> Base;`, but you could fix that by keeping track of context in a manual walk.)